# githubの[insights][Traffic]でvisitorsがclonersより少ないのはなぜ？

Tags: github

githubの[insights][Traffic]で
Unique visitors:3
Unique cloners:18
となっています。
visitしてcloneする理解ですが、Unique visitors >= Unique clonersとならないのは何故ですか？

あと皆さんの経験則で構わないのですが、visitorsもclonersも公開後数日だけあって1週間もたつとcloneもvisitも0になってしまいました。そんなものですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この記事が該当するでしょう。

誰かがリポジトリの訪問者にカウントされずにgithubリポジトリを複製できますか？
[Can someone clone your github repository without being counted in the visitors of the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55515001/9014308)
問：

> My GitHub repository shows that it's been cloned 7 times by 4 different users, but it shows that there's only 1 unique visitor to the same repository. How come that's possible?
>
> 私のGitHubリポジトリは、4人の異なるユーザーによって7回クローンされていることを示していますが、同じリポジトリへの一意の訪問者が1人だけであることを示しています。 なぜそれが可能になるのですか？

答：

> Visitors are people who visit your github page. Clones are when people do `git clone`, which doesn't involve visiting the site at all.
>
> 訪問者とは、githubページにアクセスする人です。 クローンは、人々が`git clone`を行う場合で、サイトにアクセスする必要はまったくありません。

---

Trafficの推移は、まあそんなものではないでしょうか？

旬な話題に沿っているとか、緊急の要件とか、メンバーの多い何某かのグループで宣伝されたり、内容に突っ込みどころが多かったりなどの事情があるかどうかでしょうね。